# How to bind to a TextEdit in Blazorise DataGrid using EditTemplate

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagrid, blazor, blazorise

I am new to Blazor and Blazorise...and while studying this component, I can't seem to find any material teaching how to bind a variable in a TextEdit inside an EditTemplate of a Blazorise DataGrid..

Inside my Blazorise DataGrid, I have a DataColumn (see code below):

```
<DataGridColumn
    Caption="Description"
    Editable="true"
    TItem="ProductVo"
    Field="@nameof(ProductVo.Description)">
        <DisplayTemplate>
            @($"{(context as ProductVo)?.Description}")
        </DisplayTemplate>
        <EditTemplate>
            <Validation UsePattern="true">              
                <TextEdit @bind-Text="context.CellValue" Text="@((string)context.CellValue)" Pattern="^.{3,200}$">
                    <Feedback>
                        <ValidationError>This field must be between 3 and 200 characters long.</ValidationError>
                    </Feedback>
                </TextEdit>
            </Validation>
        </EditTemplate>
</DataGridColumn>
```

In my `<TextEdit>`, I can display the value when editing by using the following code:

```
Text="@((string)context.CellValue)"
```

But it does not save, because I can't bind the `context.CellValue` using `@bind-Text="context.CellValue"`.

Please help me learn how to use Blazorise DataGrid, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing the `TextChanged` event, responsable to update the text on the `context`.
This should work:

```
<TextEdit Text="@((string)context.CellValue)" TextChanged="@(v => ( (CellEditContext)context ).CellValue = v)" Pattern="^.{3,200}$">
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you Mr. Leandro, this absolutely works!!! I just changed the `ValueChanged` to `TextChanged` because this is what the component had, and it works PERFECTLY!!! Thank you thank you very much!!!

Comment: Awesome! Fixed the answer to match the correct event!

Comment: I was copying from a NumericEdit example on the Blazorise datagrid examples and the naming is totally different. Instead of Text you have Value and ValueChanged is TextChanged. I wished they could keep the APIs a bit more consistent. Thanks for the tips by the way.